# How to read json key name in JQuery

Tags: json, jquery

I there a way to read or get the key name(if my term is correct) in this case I'm referring to  "homedata" or "faq". I want to know if is "homedata or "faq" so that I can store it in a variable and use to compare. 
for my jquery this is my script:

```
var varHolder ="";  
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
//data: data_json,
dataType: "json",
url: "sql_queries.php",
success: function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, val) {

            //read the index name here and store it to varholder
            varHolder = data[key];

            //then compare it like this
            if(varHolder == "homedata"){
                //write something to the dome
            }else if(varHolder == "faq"){
                //write something to the dome
            }
        });

    },
    error:function(){
           console.log("error fetching data. please refresh the page");//alert("Send Email Failure,Please try again");
    },
    complete:function(){
        console.log("complete");//alert("Send Email Failure,Please try again");
    }
});
```

Here is my json result:

```
[
{
"homedata":
    {
    "approve_title":"home bla blah",
    "approve_desc":"this is the approve JSON"
    }
},
{
"homedata":
    {
    "approve_title":"another home bla blah",
    "approve_desc":"tthis is the approve JSON",
    "approve_path":"backend/pdf/this is the approve JSON.pdf"
    }
},
{
"faq":
    {
    "progproj_title":"whatever JSON",
    "progproj_details":"sos sos sos"
    }
}
```

]

Comment: Why are there two keys with the name "homedata" in your json response. How will you discern the two?

Comment: that is from my database and there are two entries from the table homedata so its response is like that and I whatever the content from that is being added to the li tags. in short I'm iterating from the fields of my table then add it to li tag.

Comment: i just want to get the homedata name or the faq. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the dot notation
If your json response looks like

```
data = [{ key : value }, { key2 : value2} ]
```

You can get the value under key as

```
var value = data[0].key;
var value2 = data[1].key;
```

**EDIT**

Ok I have made a crude [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/QkTZ6/5/) It will loop over your json response and write the name of "homedata" or "faq" keys to the div. Note that it will override each time, so the last key in the json array will show in the end. This is just to illustrate for you how to get at the key names. Hopefully this helps

Comment: my response is like what I posted on my question. its inside another bracket. help please. Thank you for a quick response.

Comment: But I am afraid I do not fully understand your question. In you original question you state that you have a json response which is an array of three elements "homedata", "homedata" and "faq" and you want to know if it contains either "homedata" or "faq"??

Comment: sorry, if I made you confuse. yes, I just want to know when I loop  trough to the whole json I want to know if I'm in "homedata" or "faq". I tried using your answer but I still get the undefined. Thank you for your patience. please help.thanks

Comment: YESSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!! this is 200% perfect what I need. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

"console.log(data);" // this holds already the name of index
and so like you can do this
elementIndexName = ''+data;
or
"
$.each(data, function(key, val) {

```
        //read the index name here and store it to varholder
        varHolder = ""+data;

        //then compare it like this
        if(varHolder == "homedata"){
            //write something to the dome
        }else if(varHolder == "faq"){
            //write something to the dome
        }
    });

},
```

"

Comment: "console.log(data);"// output the whole json. I just want to know base from on my json structure what will be the name of the index or key name. if it homedata or faq. coz if it is homedata I would add it to my <li> tag in my <div id="home"> and if it is faq then I would add it to my <div id="faq">. hope that make sense

Comment: for(name in data){console.log(name);} try that